# complete (full) rootless disable

Tags: macos, sip

even though El Capitan, in recovery partition, allows the user to "disable" rootless, it should be possible to disable "even more" the SIP layer.

could someone confirm that using

```
nvram csr-active-config=%ff%00%00%00
```

would disable any feature for the SIP layer?

Comment: What are you expecting past `csrutil disable` when booted to Recovery HD? The nvram can be cleared in many cases, so wouldn't anything set there be worse off / more temporary?

Comment: I just want to investigate in undocumented SIP status